# How can I loop through list of WebElements and select one WebElement with a condition?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java. I am trying to create a method that loops through a list of WebElements to return the first WebElement that contains the text "Ooga Booga", or return null if there are no elements in the list that contains this text.

```
public class myClass {
 private static WebElement element = null;
 private static List<WebElement> elements = null;

 public static WebElement returnOneElement (WebDriver driver){
    elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("someSelector"));
    for (WebElement element : elements){
        String myText = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("classC")).getText();
        if (myText.contains("Ooga Booga")) {
            return element;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This all works fine until I run into an element that does not have this attribute:

```
String myText = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("classC")).getText();
```

How can I continue to loop through my List while ignoring any elements that do not have "someDiv" inside of it?

```
<div class="someSelector">
    <div class="classA">
    <div class="classB">
</div>

<div class="someSelector">
    <div class="classA">
    <div class="classB">
    <div class="classC">
</div>
```

I need to search for text inside div "classC".

Comment: What is someDiv? Is that the tagname div, or some other css path locator? You mention attribute, so I am assuming a classname or some sort. If so, you can probably use a different cssSelector that doesn't require that classname. Try getting the list by the element tagname. You won't have to worry about missing attribute this way

Comment: It is another CSS path locator.. I guess this analogy might help:

I am looping through a deck of cards. I keep going through these cards until I find a King of Hearts. I am searching every card `someSelector`, and checking if it is a heart `someDiv`, then checking if it is a King `myText`. This will work fine as long as every card in the deck is a heart.. but the moment I run into a Spade, this will throw a NoSuchElementException, because it does not see a Heart in the card. I am looking for a method such as `isEmpty()` but for a single `WebElement`.

Comment: Sorry, i understand what you want, but its hard to help without the html. All we'd be doing is guessing

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the question with the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use findElement-S method as shown below.

```
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        List<WebElement> mightHaveSomeDiv = element.findElements(By.cssSelector("someDiv"));

        if (mightHaveSomeDiv.size() > 0) {
            //Can iterate the list if you expect more than one div of type someDiv.
            String myText = mightHaveSomeDiv.get(0).getText();
            if (myText.contains("Ooga Booga")) {
                return element;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw, I would recommend to try and break away from static methods like this. It will make your life a living hell later on because of it being static. Everything using it starts to want static.

Anyway, lets break it down. This cssSelector will allow you to grab the child divs by the tagname instead of classname.

```
By.cssSelector(".someSelector div")
```

Now that we have a list of WebElement, which are all div elements, lets just look for the text in the div. No need to worry about class attribute

```
public static WebElement returnOneElement (WebDriver driver){
            elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".someSelector div"));
            for (WebElement element : elements){
                if(element.getText().contains("Ooga Booga")) {
                    return element;
                }
            }    
       return null;
    }
```

Alternatively, you may find the target directly with xpath locators such as

```
//div[@class='someSelector']//div[contains(.,'Ooga Booga')]
```

Be warned though, if you have multiple div that contains the text "Ooga Booga", you will get multiple WebElements, and what you do with it next may not be what you expect. Actually, this warning should also apply to the loop. It will break out of your first div element that contains "Ooga Booga". You will have to adjust the logic if you want exact match.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer.. Firstly Declare a parent web locator

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("##abc##"));
```

Now in case you want to perform any action or anything within the locator defined above then you can do it as follows:

```
element1.findElement(By.xpath("  .        //##yourFurtherLocABC")).click();

element1.findElement(By.xpath("  .      //##yourFurtherLocXYZ")).getText();
```

**Important** = Do remember to keep a `.` at the beginning of any child elements!